# A weird For To Loop in Codesys

Tags: plc, codesys

I was trying to create a timed loop into an array but than I discovered something was not working right so I got back to a simpler example. Now I discovered that my loop skips all the time 1 index and places a value. So I get in index0, index1, index3 only values. I do not understand why this is happening, I'll show my code.

```
FOR vCount := 0 TO 9 DO
    vVsample[vCount] := INT_TO_REAL(WORD_TO_INT(vVin)); 
    vCount := vCount +1;
END_FOR
```

The result will be:

```
vVsample[0] = value vVin 
vVsample[1] = did not change the value and is therefore 0
vVsample[2] = value vVin
vVsample[3] = did not change the value and is therefore 0
vVsample[4] = vVin
```

etc up to vCount = 10

I'm using Codesys V2.3 and tested this in simmulation mode

Answer (score 2):

FOR loops already do increment the iterator, thus the `vCount := vCount +1;` line is the problem. Just remove it:

```
FOR vCount := 0 TO 9 DO
    vVsample[vCount] := INT_TO_REAL(WORD_TO_INT(vVin));
END_FOR
```

Or change to a while loop:

```
vCount := 0;
WHILE vCount <> 10 DO
    vVsample[vCount] := INT_TO_REAL(WORD_TO_INT(vVin));
    vCount := vCount +1;
END_WHILE
```

Comment: Thanks I just found out

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by myself allready it is not needed to count up vCount by 1.
When doing this it will skip always one index of the array.

Silly mistake by me

Comment: Can happen to the best of us :)